# How to remove few special characters in a string in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have an input string like

```
${URL:URL=https://example.com/private/imgs/ROHAN_ZAVERI.jpg}
```

I want the output string like :

```
https://example.com/private/imgs/ROHAN_ZAVERI.jpg
```

Please let me know the regular expression to remove few special characters from the input string using java 8.

Comment: regex is not specific to Java-8, so the "java-8" tag should not be there really.

Comment: ret = inputstring.replaceAll("^[^=]+=(.*)\\}\\s*$", "$1");

Comment: String result = input.replaceAll(".*=(.*)}", "$1");

Comment: what have  you tried so far?

Comment: What if you split string and get second index from array ?
    String[] spl = str.Split('=','}');Console.WriteLine(spl[1]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use expression:

```
https?[^}]*(?=})
```

- `https` Match `http` with optional `s`.
- `[^}]*` Match everything that is not a closing `}` bracket.
- `(?=})` Lookahead for closing bracket `}`.

---

Java snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str = "${URL:URL=https://example.com/private/imgs/ROHAN_ZAVERI.jpg}";
        String patternstr = "https?[^}]*(?=})";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternstr);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
        } 
    }
```

*Output:*

```
https://example.com/private/imgs/ROHAN_ZAVERI.jpg
```

You can try the code live [here](https://ideone.com/aMoIkB).

Answer (score 1):

You can use String functions to achieve the same result as regex.

```
String str = "${URL:URL=https://example.com/privat/imgs/ROHAN_ZAVERI.jpg}";
str.substring(str.indexOf('=')+1, str.length -1);
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
https://example.com/privat/imgs/ROHAN_ZAVERI.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String Split function to get the desired ouput.

```
String str = "${URL:URL=https://example.com/privat/imgs/ROHAN_ZAVERI.jpg}";
String[] spl = str.Split('=','}');
Console.WriteLine(spl[1]);
```

output is

```
https://example.com/privat/imgs/ROHAN_ZAVERI.jpg
```